# WebBrowser control not navigating to a local document

Tags: vb.net, controls, browser

I have this code set up to navigate to a certain .html document depending on what's selected from a ListBox:

```
Private Sub FileList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FileList.SelectedIndexChanged
    HelpWindow.Navigate(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "help\" & fileArray(FileList.SelectedIndex, 1))
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I first select something in the ListBox, it successfully navigates to that file and displays it. But when I select something a second time it doesn't change.

All of the paths it's trying to navigate to are correct. I've checked this 1000 times.

Anyone have any clues why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Set your WebBrowser controls `allownavigation` property to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you're loading the list.  I think I've seen the selectedIndexChanged not fire when loaded like this:

Text 1, Value 1

Text 2, Value 1

Text 3, Value 1